# Access / Export CRM 365 Audit Log Data

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerbi, crm, dynamics-crm-365

Trying to get Microsoft CRM 365 Audit Log Data into Power BI for reporting.

Tried OData Feed Connector to CRM 365, It does connect, but can't see the Audit Log Tables.

Is there a way to extract Audit Log Records from CRM to excel or csv?

Answer (score 0):

The Dynamics 365 connector & oData connector seems to be not working for Audit entity set from [this community discussion](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/219890)  and [this PowerBI one](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Access-CRM-Audit-History-Data-in-Desktop/td-p/551615)

For understanding how/what format the Audit data is stored - I have written in detail on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492608/7920473).

Answer (score 0):

I used these instructions successfully to get the users last login information to a Power BI report:

https://crmchartguy.com/2017/09/30/use-fetchxml-in-power-bi-with-dynamics-365-customer-engagement/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes