# Need to get audit records from Dynamics 365 CE to SharePoint and then delete them

Tags: dynamics-crm, audit, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to get Audit records of Dynamics 365 CE using Microsoft Flow. I am getting the records from Audit Summery View but not the related old value to new value records. 
I am also not able to delete Audit records.

I have not been able to find any entity related to old value-new value that I can use in Microsoft Flow. 
I have tried to delete records from Microsoft Flow

I would like to get complete Audit entity records including those of old value-new value. 
Trying to delete records gives message "Delete method does not support entities of type 'Audit'. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, audit entity only supports Bulk delete and not delete.
Also bulk delete can be performed for audit records older than specific date or months.

Here is what I found from docs of Microsoft

> Audit logs are stored in blocks.  Each block contains approximately 3
>   months of logs.  You can only delete the oldest block and you cannot
>   delete the block currently in use.

I did not tried with me flow getting old and new values but I was able to use c# code to successfully get old and new value of a audit record.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was looking for a no code solution. But, can you tell me briefly how to get old and new value of audit records using c#?

Comment: https://yanivrdt.wordpress.com/2016/01/08/retrieving-audit-history-records-via-api/

link for Ref

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482663/get-audit-history-records-of-any-entity-record-as-per-crm-view)  to understand the CRM Audit concept.

You can use `RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest` for Audit data retrieval of particular record. [Code sample in MS github](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/audit-entity-data-changes#sample-audit-entity-data-changes)

Particular audit entry can be deleted from the UI using a direct button. This is part of latest version. But I don’t think there’s a code piece/endpoint for the same. [Reference](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/05/deleting-audit-log-in-dynamics-365/)

[image]