# Getting Audit Record Details from Dynamics 365 to Power BI

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, powerbi, dynamics-365

I have been able to pull down an audit table from Dynamics 365 and load it into Power BI by selecting Get Data, choosing the odata option and using `url/api/data/v9.1/audits`. I see the column `RetrieveAuditDetails`, but I don't understand why all the values say *Function*. Is there a way to extend this to show the old value/new value in the same way you can change, for example, UserIDs to be extended to the full name?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to audit data, OData/Web API REST endpoint is not so friendly in PowerBI due to the reason that the audit data is stored as delimited values in database. [Refer my answer in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492608/7920473).

If it's a javascript or .net application you can do iterative call using `RetrieveAuditDetails` function to fetch full details after getting full list using `https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/audits`. This is why you are seeing as **Function** in there.

For example:

```
var parameters = {};
var entity = {};
entity.id = "5701259e-59b8-e911-bcd0-00155d0d4a79";
entity.entityType = "audit";
parameters.entity = entity;

var retrieveAuditDetailsRequest = {
    entity: parameters.entity,

    getMetadata: function() {
        return {
            boundParameter: "entity",
            parameterTypes: {
                "entity": {
                    "typeName": "mscrm.audit",
                    "structuralProperty": 5
                }
            },
            operationType: 1,
            operationName: "RetrieveAuditDetails"
        };
    }
};

Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(retrieveAuditDetailsRequest).then(
    function success(result) {
        if (result.ok) {
            var results = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```

**Update**:
On further analysis - there is no big difference between the output schema from the above `RetrieveAuditDetails` query targeting single `auditid` or the below filtered `audits` query targeting single `recordid`.

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/audits?$filter=_objectid_value eq 449d2fd8-58b8-e911-a839-000d3a315cfc
```

The fact is either web api or fetchxml, the resultset cannot fetch the important column `changedata` which contains the changed field values - due to the restriction: `Retrieve can only return columns that are valid for read.  Column : changedata. Entity : audit`

I get this in FetchXML builder:

[image]

There is another approach but not PowerBI compatible anyway, using `RetrieveRecordChangeHistory` to target the `recordid` to get all the audit collections with old & new values. Example below:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/RetrieveRecordChangeHistory(Target=@Target)?@Target={%22accountid%22:%22449d2fd8-58b8-e911-a839-000d3a315cfc%22,%22@odata.type%22:%22Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account%22}
```

Comment: Hi Arun,
I have a question for understanding, as we do know Audit has RetrieveAuditDetails function wherein we can find more details. But then how do we tackle that w.r.t PowerBI and Webapi call. I tried using fetchxml and as we know only function is what retrieved.

so does that mean there is no direct fecth/webapi call to get data rather one extra step in between is needed?

Comment: @AnkUser pls see my update. unfortunately pushing all the raw data to staging table and massage it or massage in code before dump in staging table are the options - either way we have to put it in a staging table to consume but not direct url accessible like other entities :(

Comment: @ArunVinoth so with your statement above, could I, in theory, use a separate entity in D365 to get the values, and then pull that entity/table into Power BI?

Comment: @SQLHound that could be an overhead, why not some staging table on an on-premise sql used for replication (if you already have one)..

Comment: @ArunVinoth the customer requires the data to stay in the cloud. I realize that I am pulling the data out when I design on the Power BI desktop, but this is all development. When we advance the report to production it will all stay in the cloud.

Comment: @SQLHound try Data export service to replicate into Azure SQL server then..

Comment: Coming back around on this, so the staging table can't be brought in to Power BI by, say, M? I would think if you could program for it in javascript, you could program it in something Power BI can understand.